# Swift: Automatically scroll down to a point on UIWebView

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I want to use `UIWebView` to show a website, but it has things at the top I do not wish to show. How can I make the `UIWebView` immediately scroll to a certain part of the website?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UIWebView` has a [`scrollView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIWebView/scrollView) property:

You can set its content offset like this:

```
webView.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(0, 200)
```

An alternative might be to add the ID of a specific element to the URL, like this: https://stackoverflow.com/#h-top-questions